# What is included in the Java server jre 8? (what is not?)

Tags: java, oracle, awt

I just realized that java.awt classes are included in the server-jre 1.8.0_112 on Windows but not on Linux. Awkward cause my apps use Color and Image classes - pretty basic classes that other typical web applications may also need (at least in my opinion). I could not find any documentation about that, neither from Oracle nor in stackoverflow. Therefor no information about how to fill the gap.

So beside from the management tools and the auto-update functionality, does anyone know what else is missing in the server jre?

Is there any simple way to add awt components to the server-jre?

One reason for me to use the server-jre was to have control over the update-time for Java Runtimes. If I switch to the Standard JDK and use the .tar.gz packages, I do not get nerved by do you want to update-messages - right? What about the JDK expiration dates that Oracle documents in the release notes?

Answer (score 2):

> I just realized that java.awt classes are included in the server-jre 1.8.0_112 on Windows but not on Linux.

That is incorrect.  All standard Java SE classes are included in a Java 8 JRE for Linux.  They should be in the "rt.jar" file.  You can check that by running `jar -tvf rt.jar | grep Color.class` or similar.

Perhaps the problem is that you are trying to run a Java app on a "headless" Linux system ... without providing the required options to tell Java to use headless mode.